# passing custom data to exceptions in request_futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, concurrent.futures

I'm running the following code to make asynchronous "get" requests. The `CustomSession` class is used to add support for timing each request.

If an exception occurs or the request runs fine, I want to be able to access the `test_id` which is appended to the `futures` list, along with the URL to request. In other words, when a request runs or an exception is thrown, I want to find the `test_id` associated with the call to `session.get`.

```
from datetime import datetime
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

class CustomSession(FuturesSession):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomSession, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.timing = {}

    def request(self, method, url, *args, **kwargs):
        background_callback = kwargs.pop('background_callback', None)
        test_id = kwargs.pop('test_id', None)

        # start counting
        self.timing[test_id] = datetime.now()

        def time_it(sess, resp):
            # here if you want to time the server stuff only
            self.timing[test_id] = datetime.now() - self.timing[test_id]
            if background_callback:
                background_callback(sess, resp)
            # here if you want to include any time in the callback

        return super(CustomSession, self).request(method, url, *args,
                                                  background_callback=time_it,
                                                  **kwargs)


session = CustomSession()

futures = []
for url in ('http://httpbin.org/get?key=val',
            'http://httpasdfasfsadfasdfasdfbin.org/get?key2=val2'):

    futures.append(session.get(url, test_id=1))
for future in futures:
    try:
        r = future.result()
        print(r.status_code)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a decorator for the result() function of the future object:

```
def mark_exception(fn, id, url):
    def new_fn(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return fn(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            raise Exception("test id %d with url %s threw exception" % (id, url))
    return new_fn
```

And applied it at the end of your CustomSession.request() function, replacing the original return statement:

```
future =  super(CustomSession, self).request(method, url, *args,
                                          background_callback=time_it,
                                          **kwargs)
future.result = mark_exception(future.result, test_id, url)
return future
```

Output:

```
200
test id 1 with url http://httpasdfasfsadfasdfasdfbin.org/get?key2=val2 threw exception
```

I hope this helps.

EDIT:

If you want to get the test id for *every* future, here are two ways you can do it:

```
futures = []
for url in ('http://httpbin.org/get?key=val',
            'http://httpasdfasfsadfasdfasdfbin.org/get?key2=val2'):
    tid = 1
    future = session.get(url, test_id=tid)
    # option 1: set test_id as an attrib of the future object
    future.test_id = tid
    # option 2: put test_id and future object in a tuple before appending to the list
    futures.append((tid, future))
for tid, future in futures:
    try:
        r = future.result()
        print("tracked test_id is %d" % tid) #option 2
        print("status for test_id %d is %d" % (future.test_id, r.status_code)) #option 1
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: Thanks! You get the bounty (as soon as it will let me award it). How would I pass the `test_id` for a successful request, as well (not just an exception)? I'd like to get it through `r.test_id` or similar.